# Unable to install msoledbsql despite installing the visual c++ redistributable prerequisite

Tags: ssis, visual-studio, oledb, ssis-2016

I am trying to use Visual Studio 2022 to successfully load and build an SSIS package that targets SQL Server 2016. Documentation suggests that this is indeed supported. Per the online docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver16), I have used the visual studio installer to add in the SQL Server Data Tools. Then I have installed the SSIS extension. I am getting an error about OLEDB.

[image]

More research suggests that I need the msoledbsql driver installed. However, the installer for that complains that I need a visual c++ redistributable. I downloaded that from here and installed it without issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

[image]

[image]

I have in fact installed that as shown in my add/remove programs list. However, the msoledbsql installer refuses to install. It still insists that I need to install the visual c++. Can anyone advise a way forward?

Answer (score 3):

I had to install the x86 version of C++ Redistributable, not only the x64 that I installed at first. After x64 and x86 install I was able to install msoledbsql

Comment: Agree. Installing the x64 version C++ Redistributable does not install the x86. I need to install separately and then it allows me to install the oledb driver 19 for SQL server.